# hierarchial query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple table with person and supervisor. I have more than 200,000 entries 
and I need to derive up to 3rd level supervisor for each person.
I am advised to use connect by prior but I am not used to it much. Is there any easier way to derive?
It is oracle database and the table has just two columns person number and supervisor number. The expected output is,

PERSON  LVL1_SUP    LVL2_SUP    LVL3_SUP

Comment: What technology Oracle, MYSQL, MSSQL, etc.  Also provide table structures and sample data

Comment: An example table, please?

Comment: Please read (even if this is not for tsql) https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You can use a main select with three nested subqueries. That will give you the thirs level manager. Ugly, but will work. However, I recommend using recursive `WITH` -- the generic solution.

Comment: @TheImpaler I tried , but worst performance. Since it is not the only field I need to derive. The script runs more than an hour if I use nested subqueries.

Comment: What indexes do you have? Actually, please show the DDL (`create table ...`) statement.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
create employee (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar2(20),
  supervisor_id int
);

create index ix_employee_sup on employee (supervisor_id);

select e.*, s1.id, s2.id, s3.id
  from employee e
  left join employee s1 on e.supervisor_id = s1.id
  left join employee s2 on s1.supervisor_id = s2.id
  left join employee s3 on s2.supervisor_id = s3.id;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The actual requirement is to populate each value in a different field in the feed. But I will load it to temp table and derive. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem "the right way" - meaning, with a hierarchical query, as opposed to multiple joins - you need not only a `CONNECT BY` query as you said (which will produce the supervisors, but each will be on separate rows), but also a pivoting operation. Since Oracle 11.1, you can use the `PIVOT` operator for that.

Here is an illustration using the standard `EMP` table in the standard `SCOTT` schema. Here the "employee" column is `EMPNO` and the "supervisor" column is `MGR`. Both columns are numeric (employee numbers), but the query would work the same way if instead you had their names - as long as the names are unique (which usually they aren't, that's why we use unique id's like `EMPNO`).

You will notice that most supervisor levels are `NULL` - this is because the table has only 14 employees total. There is one employee that has three levels of supervisors above him though. Of course, where you see an employee with no supervisors at any level (even at level 1), that is the boss of all bosses (the "president" of the company, in this case).

```
select *
from   (
         select e.empno, e.mgr, level as lvl
         from   scott.emp e
         where  level <= 3
         connect by empno = prior mgr
       )
pivot  ( min(mgr) for lvl in (1 as lvl1_sup, 2 as lvl2_sup, 3 as lvl3_sup) )
;


     EMPNO   LVL1_SUP   LVL2_SUP   LVL3_SUP
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7839                                 
      7782       7839       7839           
      7844       7698                      
      7698       7839       7839           
      7902       7566       7566           
      7521       7698                      
      7566       7839       7839       7839
      7654       7698                      
      7788       7566       7566           
      7934       7782                      
      7499       7698                      
      7876       7788                      
      7369       7902                      
      7900       7698
```